# Python: How do you make a variable which can be used as an index call to slice another variable?

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, indexing

I am coming from a MATLAB background and moving over to Python. I am trying to figure out a way to set up a variable which is some vector which contains a range of indices which can then be used to slice some other array.

In MATLAB I would do this:

```
A = [2,3,4,5,6; 9,4,3,2,1; 5,4,3,2,5]; %some arbitrary matrix

begin = 2; %the first index I want to pull
end = 4; %the last index I want to pull

idx = 2:4; %the vector of indices I want

A(:,idx) %results in me pulling out the 2nd, 3rd and 4th column of A
```

Now in Python, what is the equivalent?

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[2,3,4,5,6],[9,4,3,2,1],[5,4,3,2,5]]) #some arbitrary matrix

begin = 1 #first index
end = 3 #last index

idx = ??? #This is the part I don't know! <<<-------------------

A[:,idx] #I want the same result as the Matlab example above
```

Obviously for this trivial example I could just have `idx = [1,2,3]`, but I have much more complicated scenario in real life where I cannot write out the indices manually.

I have tried using the `range`  and `np.arange` functions but they give the error that the object is not callable.

When I look at some MATLAB-to-Numpy conversions such as [here](http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/matlab-numpy.html), it suggests that the `idx = 2:4` command in MATLAB command is equivalent to `idx = range(1,3)` in Python, but this is apparently not quite true?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `A[:,np.arange(1,4)]`, `A[:, range(1,4)]` both work for me.  `A[:,1:4]` also works (though there are some subtitle differences in the result).   How are you using `range`?  `not callable` suggests you are using `()` where Python expects `[]`.

Comment: In py3, `range(n,m)` is a `range` object.  `list(range(n,m))` turns it into a list.

Answer (score 1):

You need `slice`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> A = np.array([[2,3,4,5,6],[9,4,3,2,1],[5,4,3,2,5]])
>>> begin = 1
>>> end = 3
>>> s = slice(begin, end)
>>> A[:,s]
array([[3, 4],
       [4, 3],
       [4, 3]])
```

Answer (score 0):

you would need to do this

```
idx = range(begin, end + 1)
```

notice you need to add 1 to end value because range doesn't include final value, i.e. ends in `end - 1`

Answer (score 0):

A fairly general and convenient way to "freeze" an indexing expression is `np.s_`:

```
a = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
idx = np.s_[1:3]
a[:, idx]
# array([[ 1,  2],
#        [ 5,  6],
#        [ 9, 10]])
idx = np.s_[::2, [1, 3, 0]]
a[idx]
# array([[ 1,  3,  0],
#        [ 9, 11,  8]])
```